# Read a file from an Azure DevOps Repository

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm looking to read a file from another Azure DevOps Repository than the one I'm in...

Currently I'm just storing a local copy (no git capabilities), like this:

```
locals {
  appsettings = jsondecode(file("./myfile.json"))
}
```

Now I'm trying to use the azuredevops provider (microsoft/azuredevops | Terraform Registry)

Ideally, I would just add this somewhere;

```
data "azuredevops_git_repository_file" "example" {
  repository_id       = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  file                = "mydirectory/myfile.json"
}
```

The problem is that "The provider microsoft/azuredevops does not support data source "azuredevops_git_repository_file"."

Any ideas on how to bypass this issue?

Comment: You can try to use the [Terraform http data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http) to fetch the file content from the [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP).

Comment: This did indeed solve my issue... Thanks for guiding me in the direct direction, I'll post the solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this:

```
resource "null_resource" "download_appsettings" {
  triggers = { always_run = "${timestamp()}" }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "curl -s -u \"${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.kv_secret_azuredevops_user.value}:${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.kv_secret_azuredevops_token.value}\" https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproj/_apis/git/repositories/myrepo/items?path=appsettings/appsettings.json > ${path.module}/appsettings.json"
  }
}

data "local_file" "downloaded_appsettings" {
  filename   = "${path.module}/appsettings.json"
  depends_on = [null_resource.download_appsettings]
}
```

And then I'm just defining this in locals

```
locals {
  appsettings = jsondecode(data.local_file.downloaded_appsettings.content)
}
```

So I can use these appsettings later in my App Service like this

```
  app_settings = merge({ for item in local.appsettings[*] : "${item.name}" => item.value }, {
    "KEY"    = "VALUE"
  })
```